# Trying to Upload .dat.gz file as as a base64 string using Jmeter http

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing, beanshell

I have to send a https rest API request through jmeter

body of the request :
{"auth":{"token":"${SessionID}"},"clientGUID":"B0DC2BE4-D744-45c6-AEF6-EBEF319A336B","taskID":"${TaskID}","chunkID":"1","chunkSize":3375134,"fileName":"${curFileTime}downloadLogsBig.dat.gz","bytes":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}

where XXXX is the byte array of file. Need help achieve this with the best method do this

byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(uploadFile.toPath());
uploadReq.setBytes(fileContent); --> Java to set XXXX

Comment: Can you pass authentication info via HTTP Headers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try amending your request payload as:

```
{
  "auth": {
    "token": "${SessionID}"
  },
  "clientGUID": "B0DC2BE4-D744-45c6-AEF6-EBEF319A336B",
  "taskID": "${TaskID}",
  "chunkID": "1",
  "chunkSize": 3375134,
  "fileName": "${curFileTime}downloadLogsBig.dat.gz",
  "bytes": "${bytes}"
}
```

and populate the "bytes" using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

```
vars.put('bytes', new File('jmeter.sh').bytes as String)
```

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks a lot for helping, my actual intenstion is to sent a file of huge size as set of chunks for e.g 20MB files to 2 10MB chunks, as a first step I was trying to send a smaller file. I tried with the above code you shared by changing 'jmeter.sh' to my file path but JMeter froze when clicking the sampler and the response was indicated as failed. I couldn't see the request or response as the application froze. My file is actually in .dat.zip format and I need to send the file as bytes. By 'Jmeter.sh' did you mean my actual file?

Comment: I was actually trying to do the reverse of this request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000487/how-to-convert-receving-bytes-array-to-string-using-jmeter-beanshell .

Comment: In the referenced answer the file is being sent as a base64 string, not a byte array, you need to do something like `vars.put('bytes', new File('jmeter.sh').bytes.encodeBase64().toString())`

Comment: According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you [shouldn't be using Beanshell at least since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)

Comment: What should I provide in jmeter.sh? Could you please help here a bit more steps? Thank you