# How to convert receiving bytes array as base64 to string and write to file in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, https, jmeter, beanshell

{"result":{"success":true,"errMsg":"error"},"bytes":"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjxCdXNpbmVzc1J1bGUgeG1sbnM6eHNpPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYS1pbnN0YW5jZSIgeG1sbnM6eHNkPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYSI+DQogICAgPEN"}

I am receiving a response like above, I need to convert the bytes to a string and write to file using Jmeter , How is this possible, I am able to write to file using extracting the value using JSON extractor and write to file

```
receivedbytes =  vars.get("recvBytes");
log.info(receivedbytes);
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\tmp\\getSoftwarePackage.out", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(receivedbytes);
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

where recvBytes is bytes in response

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive it after decoding.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; String receivedbytes = 

vars.get("recvBytes"); 
log.info(receivedbytes); 
log.info("Decoding base64 format");
String decoded_response = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(receivedbytes));
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\tmp\\getSoftwarePackage.out", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(decoded_response); 
out.close(); 
fstream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), not Beanshell
2. You're receiving not bytes array but a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) String
3. If you will be writing the same file with multiple threads you will run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting in data loss

Assuming all above:

1. Amend your code to look like as follows:

   ```
   vars.put('decodedBytes', new String(vars.get('recvBytes').decodeBase64()))
   ```
2. Add the next line to [user.properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables):

   ```
   sample_variables=decodedBytes
   ```
3. Use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) to write the variable into the file

If you don't "afraid" of the race condition or using JMeter for functional testing running it with 1 virtual user you can amend the code as follows:

```
new File('C:\\tmp\\getSoftwarePackage.out').text = new String(vars.get('recvBytes').decodeBase64())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can we avoid race condition and write it into multiple file

Comment: Your input was soo helpful. Folled this https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin almost achived what I am doing. But now facing and exception due to response size, Excepton is in view result tree and also in listener. Any way to overcomethis?

Comment: Figured the issue on file size buffer. I sent this  kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.FFWBufferSize=100000000 in user.properties and it worked. Now Looking to see if I can create multiple different file for each request

Comment: Is it possible to write the Flexible file writer output as multiple file with timestamp or something